# How to hide tabBar from a child stack to parent stack navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen 'About' which doesn't need a tabBar but other siblings to that screen must have tabBar.

the third element in the tab named 'Settings' have a default class in which i used a stack navigator.

```
export default class Setting extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
        tabBarVisible:true // if i place false here the tabBar is invisible on all screens in below specified stack.
    };

    render() {

        return (

            <SettingStack />

        );
    }
}


export const SettingStack = StackNavigator({
    // screenname : { screen : ImportedClassname }
    settingsscreen: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    first: { screen: first },
    second: { screen: second },
    about: { screen: About },
    third: { screen: third },
});
```

How can i hide the tabBar only on 'about' screen .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the default export class and use that "settingstack" in your parent navigation tree. it will work for sure if not please get back...